# Beginning Incidence Geometry: Flags & types

Tags: projective-geometry

So far, I understand that type means something like a line or a point but what does this notation mean?: type(x) such that x is an element of F? Or what does type(x) in general mean?

For flags, I have that they are defined as pairwise incident elements of some set. 
 But what exactly is a chamber, my book says a chamber has order I, but what does that mean(to have order I, how can I tell)? What is the order of I? There is also a theorem that says the order of type(F), where F means flag, is equal to the order of F. Order as in cardinnality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking up keywords from your question in Google Books, I found [*Foundations of Incidence Geometry*](http://books.google.de/books?id=RN_k0Yrs4bQC&lpg=PA2&dq=flag%20type%20order%20chamber%20incident%20set&hl=de&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q=flag%20type%20order%20chamber%20incident%20set&f=false) by Johannes Ueberberg.

> what does this notation mean?: type(x) such that x is an element of F? Or what does type(x) in general mean?

This means that $x$ (e.g. a point or a line, in higher dimensions perhaps even more alternatives) is an element of some set $F$ (which I guess stands for “flag”) and you are talking about its *type*, i.e. you want to know whether this particular $x$ is a point or a line.

Take for example the square with corners $A,B,C,D$ and edges $a,b,c,d$. Then you'd get $\operatorname{type}(A)=\text{point}$ but $\operatorname{type}(a)=\text{line}$. At least if your *set of possible types* is $I=\{\text{point},\text{line}\}$, as opposed to $I=\{\text{vertex},\text{edge}\}$, $I=\{0,1\}$ or something else. The actual names don't matter for the definitions, but sure help intuition.

> But what exactly is a chamber

A chamber is a flag where every possible type occurs once. So if you have $I=\{\text{point},\text{line}\}$, then a flag would be a point and a line incident to it. Think about higher dimensions, where you have a polytope consisting of vertices, edges and faces. A chamber is a set consisting of one face, one edge of that face, and vertex of that edge.

> There is also a theorem that says the order of type(F), where F means flag, is equal to the order of F.

Due to the definition of the incidence relation, no flag can contain more than one element of a given type. This is because the elements of a flag must be pairwise incident, and incident elements of the same type must be identical. So $\lvert\operatorname{type}(F)\rvert$ is the number of different types occuring in your flag, while $\lvert F\rvert$ is the number of different elements, but since no two elements can have the same type, these cardinalities must be the same.

So in the characterization of a chamber, as I stated it above, it is equivalent whether you require every type to occur *at least* once or *exactly* once.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, you are very helpful! I have trouble reading this text and it is the exact text I am reading, the one which you cited.